# Time complexity for the Polynomial Function?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Give an algorithm that evaluates an input polynomial

a<sub>n</sub> x<sup>n</sup>+a<sub>n-1</sub> x<sup>n-1</sup>+⋯+a<sub>1</sub> x+a<sub>0</sub>

For a given value of `x` in time Ω(n<sup>2</sup>) and O(n).
I tried to proof this but unable to find a suitable algorithm, can anyone help me to get the idea?

Comment: How can this possibly be n^2? There are n+1 terms, each one computed in O(1) time, with n O(1) additions.

Comment: @Adam: you cannot calculate x^n in O(1).

Comment: Are you assuming that the numbers are big-ints with arbitrary size? If they are fixed, it is `O(N)`.

Comment: @usr When speaking about exponents this assumption is basically a must, otherwise for `x >=2` there is no point in big O without this assumption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Horner's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornersRule.html) to evaluate it in O(n):

`(..( (a_n x + a_(n-1) ) x + a_(n-2) ) x  + ... + a_0)`.

Comment: What about the Ω(n2)?

Comment: @user1920333 Just throw an extra `for(i=1;i<n;i++) for(j=1;j<n;j++) {}` loop, and disable compiler optimizations. You can always get the algorithm worse as much as you want.

Comment: @user1920333 Or probably what your teacher is looking for: `f(x,n) = (n==0?1:x*f(x,n-1))` and sum `an*f(x,n) + (an-1)*f(x,n-1) + ... + a0`